# EF Core OnDelete Cascade fails on simple one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I've configured the relationship as follows:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Formula>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Versions)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey("ID_FORMULA")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

When I delete a `Formula` with several `Versions` it complaints with this message:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException : An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>   ---- System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_FORMULA_VERSION_FORMULA". The conflict occurred in
>   database "XXXX", table
>   "dbo.FORMULA_VERSION", column 'ID_FORMULA'. The statement has
>   been terminated.

I'm using SQL Server (Azure). What's the problem?

Comment: Check your SQL server if your table actually has `ON DELETE CASCADE` when you script out the table. You might not have migrated this change.

Comment: I've checked the definition of the Formula table and it doesn't mention the ON DELETE CASCADE anywhere. The problem is that I cannot modify the DB, as it's given to us by the customer. I understand that the table needs a change on its definition to make EF Cascade Delete work, doesn't it?

Comment: What's in the code regarding the `OnDelete` behaviour is completely irrelevant as its there for migration purposes only, so if you haven't migrated your db then that is your problem. If you can't migrate db then you need to cascade the delete manually.

Comment: The, how should I remove the orphan entities? is there a common way to approach this scenario? Thank you!

Comment: Common way is to migrate your database with proper `OnDelete` behaviour. Your own circumstances are not common, that's why you can't use common approach. Uncommon way would be to load the related entities and delete them.

Comment: You need to load the dependent entities. I EF will cascade delete the entities according to the model if they are tracked by EF. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete